# Is there a specific error type that should be used to express an unmet requirement in javascript?

Tags: javascript, throw

When creating a module that will be used by others, is there a standardized, specific error type that should be thrown to express an unmet requirement?

*I'm a function. I need x. x is undefined and I'm upset about it. What do I throw?*

Comment: Take a look at the error thrown by built-in functions.

Comment: `throw "Error: question shows very little research and no attempts at solving the problem"`

Comment: I actually have been researching it. Thank you for having your nose too high in the air to be useful though. Sorry for asking a question on SO.

Comment: so you consider that putting a status and a description in an exception is not useful, ok.

Comment: Your attitude is definitely not useful. I know how to `throw new Error("Hey looked I typed something");` I was looking for an answer with a little merit.

Comment: Then post a question with a little merit

Comment: Your opinion is noted, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the standard practices for throwing JavaScript Exceptions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825427/what-are-the-standard-practices-for-throwing-javascript-exceptions)

Comment: You've obviously missed the essence of the question. I'm asking about a standard error type, not custom, standard.

Comment: @NicholasKyriakides mostly the "nose in the air" comment.  But maybe a little because that question was asked six years ago.  Things might have changed.  Maybe someone took a stab at something like this

Comment: @Tibrogargan just because you believe something has been answered to someone else's satisfaction, does not mean that it has. Your comment was very sarcastic, and I called you on it. If you would like to answer people's questions and be helpful, then do that. You do not add anything constructive by being arrogant and rude to people on the internet.

Comment: @KyleRichardson where is your research on the matter?  Did you look at the existing standard errors to see if anything was suitable?  I don't see where your question eliminates any of them as being unsuitable.  What else did you look at?  Anything?  Why can't you just throw a formatted string?  Why can't you make your own rules for how you throw exceptions.  Just because no standard exists doesn't mean you can't do something yourself that follows rules

Comment: This will be the last time I respond to you. I didn't realize you needed all of that information to answer my question. Yes I know the types of errors in javascript, yes I know how to throw formatted strings, and make custom error objects with logging methods etc. I was interested if there was anything that anyone has encountered over years of programming that is somewhat standardized so that I could provide such standardization to people when I create things. My apologizes for asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike strongly typed C-style languages such as C# and Java, JavaScript doesn't have many out-of-the-box exception types.

`try..catch` is also a little-used feature of the language, so it's not overly common to see people explicitly `throw` in JavaScript.

With the relatively recent introduction of promises to the language, and--in particular--[`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) `try..catch` is becoming more common.

As far as *what* errors to throw specifically, it's always up to the individual developer, and I recommend documenting what errors your API will throw. That said, there are a handful of *common* errors that are built into the language and have natural use cases:

- [`Error`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error) - obviously this is the generic class to throw a generic error
- [`RangeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError) - throw this if input is not in the appropriate range, such as when you expect a positive number and receive a negative.
- [`ReferenceError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError) - typically this is meant for variables that don't exist, but this can also be useful for APIs that expose data access via strings. I.E.:

  ```
  getData('foo') //ReferenceError: 'foo' does not exist in data`
  ```
- [`TypeError`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypeError) - this represents an error when a value is not of the right type (this is probably the one you want). For example, you have a callback parameter that requires a function, and the user provides a string.

There are more built-in `Error` types than these, but they tend to be much less common in the wild.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. That is what I expected but I wanted to affirm that I was handling things properly. I believe the documentation step is the most important component.

Answer (score 1):

As MDN example, you can define a new Exception class then throw it

Here is example. Hope that helps :)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/throw#Throw_an_object

Comment: Thank you but I know how to make custom errors. I was looking for a standard response to this situation.

Comment: I don't really get your question. Or can you provide a example of your question for more clear

Answer (score 0):

It's really up to you as the developer. You should try to make your code die gracefully though by using try and throwing exceptions. You can use console to log different messages in different ways and you can make it say what ever you want.

Here is a good resourse for highliting console messages .. https://coderwall.com/p/m2trga/enhance-your-js-console-logging-messages

```
console.log('console.log');
console.info('console.info');
console.debug('console.debug');
console.warn('console.warn');
console.error('console.error');
```

in terms of missing parameters, I would log a warning on ...

```
if (typeof name === "undefined") {
    // ...
}
```