# Extending JavaScript errors / exceptions

Tags: javascript, exception, inheritance, native

I was developing a small JS library and was to use there custom Error exceptions.

So, I decided to inherit them (ORLY?) from native Javascript Error object in this way:

```
var MyError = function(){
    Error.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
};

// Inherit without instantiating Error
var Surrogate = function(){};
Surrogate.prototype = Error.prototype;
MyError.prototype = new Surrogate();

// Add some original methods
MyError.prototype.uniqueMethod = function(){...}
```

Looks like usual inheritance.. But!

```
var err = new MyError("hello! this is text!");
console.log(err.message); // is giving me empty string!
```

I have read articles about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript) and on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Error), but all of them saying me to use something like this:

```
var MyError = function(msg){
    this.message = msg;
};
```

But my question is - if not in the constructor of Error, then where message is initialized?
May be somebody knows how Error native constructor works?

Thanks!

P.S. If it interesting - I was developing [Enum.js](https://github.com/gobwas/Enum.js) library.

Comment: Making it as simple as possible:

`var obj = new Error(); Error.call(obj, "Hello, world!");`

This doesn’t work either. `Error` is weird.

Comment: @minitech: *"`Error` is weird."* +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing is fine. It's `Error` that's the problem.

On this line:

```
Error.prototype.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
```

...you're calling `Error` (indirectly) as a normal function call rather than as part of a `new` expression, and the [defined behavior for `Error` when you call it as a non-constructor function](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.1) is to create a new, blank `Error` and return it (rather than populating `this`).

Now, in the normal case, what you're doing with the prototype would make the standard check for whether it was called as a constructor (`if (this instanceof Error)`) work. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to be doing that, and whatever check it uses to determine how it was called doesn't seem to be immediately amenable to what you're trying to do. Even this (which is just a test, not meant to be something you'd actually do):

```
MyError.prototype = Error.prototype; // You wouldn't normally do this, it's just a test
```

...didn't solve it.

[This answer to another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8804539/157247) points to a possible workaround (basically, let `Error` create the object and then return that from `MyError`):

```
function MyError(message) {
    var e = new Error(message);
    // ...apply your enhancements to `e`
    return e;
}
```

Not amazingly satisfying as you'd have to put your extensions directly on the object rather than use the prototype chain, but if `Error` refusees to play ball, your options are a bit limited...

Comment: Thanks for answer. So, seems I need to do smth like: `MyError = function(msg){ var err = new Error(); this.msg = msg; this.stack = err.stack; ...}

Comment: @gobwas: I just updated the answer with one possible workaround. I don't like it, but I'm not sure you get a lot of choice. *Edit* Or, yeah, you could do it that way around.