# Can an object *truly* inherit from Error.prototype?

Tags: javascript, oop, inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

[There are other similar questions on this topic, but none of them answer the question I'm asking here, AFAICT.  (I.e. the answers I have read all explain why a particular construct fails to do with the questioner is trying to do, and in some cases they offer alternative ways to get the desired results.  But no thread answers the question of how to achieve *true inheritance* from `Error.prototype`.)]

The best I've managed to do is still basically useless:

```
function MyErr(message) {
  var tmp = Error.apply(this, arguments);
  for (var prop in tmp) { this[prop] = tmp[prop]; }
}
MyErr.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

Even after "manually" copying properties (a sure sign of a "busted inheritance"), the object returned by `new MyErr("whatever")` is still ***not even remotely close*** to what I would consider "an instance that inherits from `Error.prototype`".  The deviations from expected behavior are really too many to list here—they pop up everywhere I look!—, but, for starters,

```
console.log((new Error("some error")).toString())     // "Error: some error"
console.log((new MyErr("another error")).toString())  // "Error"
                                                      // expected
                                                      // "MyError: another error"

console.log((new Error("some error")).constructor)    // "Error()"
console.log((new MyErr("another error")).constructor) // "Error()"
                                                      // expected:
                                                      // "MyError()"
```

<sub>(In case anyone is wondering, no, `constructor` is not one of the properties that gets copied in `MyErr`'s `for` loop.  I checked.)</sub>

Can an object ***truly inherit*** from `Error.prototype`?

Given that to answer the analogous question for `Array` requires [a lengthy treatise](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/), I can't reasonably expect a full answer to my question here, but I hope I can get a pointer to such full answer.

---

**UPDATE:** I tried out Bergi's proposal.  Below I provide a full, self-contained implementation.<sup>1</sup>

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html><head><meta charset="utf-8"></head><body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
      function MyErr(message) {
        var tmp = Error.apply(this, arguments);
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(tmp).forEach(function(p) {
          console.log('property: ' + p);
          Object.defineProperty(this, p,
                                Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(tmp, p));
        }, this);
        console.log('done creating ' + this);
      }
      MyErr.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
        constructor: {value:MyErr, configurable:true},
        name: {value:"MyErr", configurable:true}
      });

      var error = new Error("some error");
      var myerr = new MyErr("another error");

      console.log(error.toString());
      console.log(myerr.toString());

      console.log(error.constructor);
      console.log(myerr.constructor);
    });
  </script></body></html>
```

The output I get in the Firebug console is this:

```
done creating MyErr                                         testjs.html (line 13)
Error: some error                                           testjs.html (line 23)
MyErr                                                       testjs.html (line 24)
Error()                                                     testjs.html (line 26)
MyErr(message)                                              testjs.html (line 27)
```

Note in particular that the output does not include any lines beginning with `property:`.  This means that the `console.log` statement within the `forEach` loop in `MyErr` *never gets executed* (and presumably the same goes for the rest of the `forEach` callback).

If I replace the `forEach` loop with

```
        for (var p in tmp) {
          console.log('property: ' + p);
          Object.defineProperty(this, p,
                                Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(tmp, p));
        };
```

...then three new lines get prepended to the output (line numbers omitted):

```
property: fileName
property: lineNumber
property: columnNumber
```

This shows that not even `message` is among the `tmp` properties accessible this way (though `message` does show up among `tmp`'s properties in Firebug's variable inspector, along with *a bazillion* of other ones that are also not shown in the console output above).

Also, the explicitly-set `name` property does make an appearance in the output of `myerr.toString()`, but still this method does not behave in the same way as `error.toString()`.

I do get the expected output from `myerr.toString()` if I add the following line at the end of the `MyErr` function:

```
this.message = message;
```

...but I get little comfort from this, because this maneuver, along with most of the other maneuvers I've shown above, have been ad hoc kluges aimed at the specific examples that I posted, but these were intended only as an illustration of what appears to be a deeper problem, namely a complete breakdown of the expected inheritance model.

The purpose of this question is to find out how to achieve "true inheritance" from `Error.prototype`, and if that is not possible, then to simulate it as closely as possible, having a *clear picture* of the extent to which the simulation fails to implement the full inheritance model.  I stress that the latter of these two alternatives should not be confused with the strategy of *incrementally patching* some flawed implementation every time we happen to notice some new way in which it fails to conform to expectation.  This "incremental patching" approach provides the ideal environment for silent bugs, and is thus a recipe for insanity.

---

**UPDATE2:** There seems to be no end to JS's unpredictability.  I just discovered that, at least in the Firebug console, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` produces a different value depending on whether its argument is a non-atomic expression or a variable to which the same non-atomic expression has been previously assigned.      <sup><sub>wtf?</sub></sup>

For example, the following is copy-pasted directly from an interaction in the Firebug console (I've added one empty line before each command, for ease of reading):

```
>>> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Error("not assigned"))
[]

>>> errorvar = new Error("assigned")
Error: assigned
(no source for debugger eval code)

>>> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(errorvar)
["fileName", "lineNumber", "message", "stack"]
```

(The output right after the assignment to `errorvar` seems to have to do with the fact that an `Error` object was created, even though it was not `throw`n.  The same output appears even if one deletes everything to the left of `new` in that line.)

And if that were not enough, if I run this from within a script

```
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Error("not assigned")))
var errorvar = new Error("assigned");
console.log(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(errorvar));
```

the output in the Firebug console is

```
[ ]
[ ]
```

I don't know if this erratic behavior is due to ECMAScript5, or JavaScript, or Firefox, or Firebug, or what, but it's driving me insane...

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> I posted this self-contained implementation to encourage others to try it out.  If there is one thing I have learned about JavaScript is that, no matter how simple the code, and no matter how much you think you know about JavaScript, the only way to know what some JavaScript code is going to do is to run it.  Sadly, JavaScript programming still remains *an embarrassingly experimental activity*.  JS is not for the armchair programmer!  :)</sup>

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/8802845/218196.

Comment: @FelixKling: Thanks.  I have read those, and other similar SO threads.  They all explain why a *particular* construct fails to work.  This does not address my question.  My question is "*how* can I implement an object that fully inherits from `Error.prototype`".  Please see the article on `Array` that I linked for an example of what I'm trying to achieve with `Error`.

Comment: error has native code ctor and methods. You can only a) extend the error object, or write wrappers which do what you want and internally use the Error object.

Comment: The firebug and chrome consoles are magical environments that don't have entirely same properties as normal js environments. One thing in particular that has bitten me in chrome console is that objects are retained forever if you set them to null in console.

Answer (score 4):

Well I don't know what else you could need apart from the stack trace and `instanceof`. Try this:

```
function MyError(message) {
    this.name = this.constructor.name;
    this.message = message;
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) {
        Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor);
    } else {
        var stack = new Error().stack;
        if (typeof stack === "string") {
            stack = stack.split("\n");
            stack.shift();
            this.stack = stack.join("\n");
        }
    }
}
MyError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
    constructor: {
        value: MyError,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
});
try {
    throw new MyError("message");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e + "");
    console.log(e.stack + "");
}
try {
    throw new Error("message");
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e + "");
    console.log(e.stack + "");
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VjAC7/1/

Chrome

```
MyError: message
MyError: message
    at window.onload (http://fiddle.jshell.net/VjAC7/1/show/:44:11)
Error: message
Error: message
    at window.onload (http://fiddle.jshell.net/VjAC7/1/show/:51:11)
```

Firefox

```
MyError: message
window.onload@http://fiddle.jshell.net/VjAC7/1/show/:44
Error: message
window.onload@http://fiddle.jshell.net/VjAC7/1/show/:51
```

IE10

```
Error: message 
Error: message
    at onload (http://fiddle.jshell.net/VjAC7/1/show/:44:5) 
Error: message 
Error: message
    at onload (http://fiddle.jshell.net/VjAC7/1/show/:51:5)
```

Answer (score 2):

To me it seems as if the Object created below inherits all the properties of the Error object and behaves identically... Perhaps you can explain how/if it differs?

```
var MyErr = function(message) {
  this.name = 'My Error';
  this.message = message;
}
MyErr.prototype = new Error();
MyErr.prototype.constructor = MyErr;

throw new MyErr('Uhoh!') // My Error: Uhoh!
```

On the prototype I can see `get stack` and `set stack` inhertited from Error.

Comment: I posted ***explicit examples*** showing how the actual behavior differs from expected behavior.

Comment: @kjo Sorry, I guess I don't understand the discrepancies you're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

As of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), yes, you can truly subclass `Error` (and `Array`). On any recent Chrome, Firefox, Safari, or Edge:

```js
class MyError extends Error {
  myOwnMethod() {
    console.log("MyError method");
  }
}
try {
  throw new MyError("Thrown");
}
catch (e) {
  console.log(e instanceof Error);   // true
  console.log(e instanceof MyError); // true
  console.log(e.message);            // "Thrown"
  e.myOwnMethod();
}
```

---

Re this part of your "Update":

> This shows that not even `message` is among the `tmp` properties accessible this way (though message does show up among tmp's properties in Firebug's variable inspector, along with a bazillion of other ones that are also not shown in the console output above).

That tells us that `message` wasn't an "own" property (so didn't show up in the result of `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`), and wasn't enumerable (so didn't show up in `for-in`). So apparently it was a non-enumerable inherited property.

If so, that was a spec violation that's since been fixed. The [spec at the time](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.11.1) was quite clear: Calling `Error` without `new` is just like calling it *with* `new`, and when you call `Error` with `new` and pass it an argument, it's supposed to set an **own** property called `message` on the newly-created instance, initialized with `String(theArgumentYouPassed)`.

Here in 2017, it's correct: `Error("foo").hasOwnProperty("message")` is `true` on Chrome and Firefox, which is in keeping with both the old spec and the [current one](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-error-message).

---

Re your "Update 2":

> For example, the following is copy-pasted directly from an interaction in the Firebug console (I've added one empty line before each command, for ease of reading):
>
> ```
> >>> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(new Error("not assigned"))
> []
>
> >>> errorvar = new Error("assigned")
> Error: assigned
> (no source for debugger eval code)
>
> >>> Object.getOwnPropertyNames(errorvar)
> ["fileName", "lineNumber", "message", "stack"]
> ```

If it did that in 2013 in Firebug, you'll be glad to know it doesn't do that in 2017 in Firefox's built-in developer tools. Nor in Chrome's. The results of the two calls to `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` is consistent (now). The behavior you described seeing is bizarre, I wish I'd had a chance to try it with 2013's Firefox+Firebug. It's extremely hard to buy that simply assigning the object reference to a variable would have an effect on what you get back when passing that reference into `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
function MyErr(message) {
  var tmp = Error.apply(this, arguments);
  Object.getOwnPropertyNames(tmp).forEach(function(p) {
    Object.defineProperty(this, p, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(tmp, p));
  }, this);
}
MyErr.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype, {
  constructor: {value:MyErr, configurable:true},
  name: {value:"MyErr", configurable:true}
});
```

This will copy even non-enumerable properties from `tmp` to `this`, it will [reset the `.constructor` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12622137/what-is-the-constructor-property-really-used-for) and it will set the `.name` property as expected by [`.toString`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.11.4.4).

```
> (new MyErr("another error")).toString()
"MyErr: another error"
> (new MyErr("another error")).constructor
Function MyErr
```

Comment: That's odd. Can you post what version of FF you are using?

Comment: 23.01 on Windows 7; what results do you get with the self-contained implementation I posted?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to inherit from error, try to extend a new error object and return it
I wrote a quick example how to achieve this here: http://jsfiddle.net/Elak/tvXqC/2/

Basically you can extend your returned object and also overwrite the error name (which then gets used in console or wherever you log that error

```
var Errors = {};
(function(){
    var myError = function(message){
        return $.extend(new Error(arguments[0]),{
            printExample : function(){
                $("#out").html("Error: " + this.name + ": " + this.message);
            }
        },
        // overwriting error object properties. default for name is Error...
        // this way you can control the log output
        {
            name: "ExceptionNameWhichWillShowInLog"
        }
        );
    };
    Errors.MyError = myError;
})();
```

the object with the function printExample is now the place for your own methods (replaces the prototype implementation...).

You have actually the same access to this where this is now the instance of a "real" error object and you can do with that instance whatever you want...