# Stack cannot be output for custom error with super() called under Babel?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Refer [this](http://azimi.me/2015/09/23/high-custom-error-class-es6.html), the Custom Errors in ES6 can be written as following:

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.message = message;
    this.name = 'MyError';
  }
}
```

> There is no need for `this.stack = (new Error()).stack;` trick thanks to `super()` call.

However, I test it under [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/)

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message);
    this.message = message;
    this.name = 'MyError';
    //this.stack = (new Error()).stack;
    //Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor.name);
  }
}

var myerror = new MyError("test");
console.log(myerror.stack)
```

**There is NO stack information unless the code `this.stack = (new Error()).stack;` or `Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor.name);` is invoked.**

But I test the above code snippet **without** `this.stack = (new Error()).stack;` or `Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor.name);` under `Chrome console`.

Output:

```
MyError: test
    at MyError (<anonymous>:3:28)
    at <anonymous>:12:19
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:875:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:808:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:664:21)
```

Should I consider this is one defect on `Babel` or Chrome issue? Or miss understanding the `super()`?

**Update**

According to V8 codes, the `stack` of `Error`

```
captureStackTrace = function captureStackTrace(obj, cons_opt) {
  // Define accessors first, as this may fail and throw.
  ObjectDefineProperty(obj, 'stack', { get: StackTraceGetter,
                                       set: StackTraceSetter,
                                       configurable: true });
```

Base on my understanding, since the `stack` is one property of `Error`, after `supper()` is called, then it is not necessary to invoke `captureStackTrace` in `MyError` class. Am I missing something?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089801/extending-error-in-javascript-with-es6-syntax ?

Comment: Extending built in classes is not very well supported yet in browsers. Babel can't do anything about this.

Comment: Are you actually chrome-only? If so, you can use native ES6 classes and tell Babel not to transpile them. Then extending error will work.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, in order to properly extend `Error` class in V8 you should call

```js
Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
```

in it's constructor, e.g.:

```js
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor (message) {
    super()
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
    Object.assign(this, {name: 'MyError', message})
  }
}
```

**N.B.:** Bear in mind that not all browsers support `Error.captureStackTrace`, so you may have to make it optional.

Alternatively, you could use [`es6-error` npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/es6-error) to deal with all this stuff automatically:

```js
import ExtendableError from 'es6-error';

class MyError extends ExtendableError {
  // everything is taken care of
}
```

Comment: Since `super()` is invoked in `MyError` subclass, I think it is not necessary to invoke `captureStackTrace`. Please see my question update.

Comment: @zangw `Error.captureStackTrace` is a part of [V8 Stack Trace API](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Stack%20Trace%20API#stack-trace-collection-for-custom-exceptions) and can't be avoided. Calling `supper()` is not enough to properly extend V8 error class.