# instanceOf returns false although debugger shows the object

Tags: javascript, inheritance, typescript, prototype

I have this simple function which should return true[image: console debugger]

I returns false though, but console debugger shows that this is the UIError object. Nevertheless:

```
exception.originalException instanceOf UIError
```

returns false ! I see in the debugger that it is indeed an UIError class. Why ?

UIError extends Error class

[image]

```
private isAnUIError(exception: any): boolean {
    return (exception.originalException) instanceof UIError || exception instanceof  UIError;
}

export class UIError extends Error {
constructor (private message: string) {
super();
this.message = message;
 }
```

Comment: What is `UIError`?

Comment: Not sure, it could be that it is *the* `UIError` *class* itself? Try `exception.originalException == UIError`. Alternatively, does at least `exception.originalException instanceof Error` work?

Comment: UIError extends Error

Comment: exception.originalException instanceOf Error returns true, but I don'w want that. I want only catch the UIError objects

Comment: @adamnowak Can you please post your code that allows us to reproduce this, instead of showing pretty debugger pictures? Notice that the "name" (or "class name") of an object in the debugger can be quite misleading, especially in multiframe environments.

Comment: Are you using `instanceOf` or `instanceof`?

Comment: How is `UIError` defined? If it is defined incorrectly it will be an `Error` with the name `UIErrror` which will display in the debugger as a `UIError` but cause `instanceof` to fail. The answer lies purely in how `UIError` is implemented.

Comment: I added the implementation of UIError and the checko function

Comment: @adamnowak: And how do you call it? `isAnUIError(new UIError)`? Also, how are you transpiling and where are you executing this? Notice that many enviroments simply don't support subclassing builtins yet.

Answer (score 0):

If typescript is anything like Babel ES6 `Error` can not be extended like a normal class could be. This is nasty wart in JavaScript. The work around is to directly manage the new error's prototype. I explained this in [another SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35858868/227176) regarding ES6 and Babel transpiling.

Here is how I would expect this to look:

```
class UIError {
  constructor(message) {
    this.name = 'UIError';
    this.message = message;
    this.stack = new Error().stack; // Optional
  }
}
UIError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

Keep in mind that `super()` does nothing with `Error` because `Error` is *not* a typical constructor function (class). It means nothing to perform

```
Error.apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 0))
```

(which is essentially what a `super()` does) since the `Error()` function doesn't do anything with `this` but instead returns a new Error. This is a know caveat regarding `Error` in JavaScript.

Comment: You will need to distinguish between ES5 `Error` implementations and ES6 ones.

Comment: I tried your approach but got: "TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'prototype' of function 'class MyError'"

Comment: @rinderonthestorm I think babel is in transition. To fix your error don’t use `class` and go back to `function`. I also think newer versions of babel will allow extending `Error` as expected. Not sure.