# Why don't Mocha/Chai treat babel custom errors the same as regular custom errors?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, mocha.js, babeljs, chai

This works in Mocha/Chai:

```
describe('Chai throw() with old-style custom errors', ()=> {

  // old way
  function ES5Error(message = 'todo', value) {
    this.name = 'ES5Error';
    this.message = message;
  }
  ES5Error.prototype = new Error();

  it('catches ES5Errors', ()=> {
    var err = new ES5Error('This is a bad function.');
    var fn = function () { throw err; }
    expect(fn).to.throw(ES5Error);
    expect(fn).to.throw(Error);
    expect(fn).to.throw(/bad function/);
    expect(fn).to.not.throw('good function');
    expect(fn).to.throw(ES5Error, /bad function/);
    expect(fn).to.throw(err);
  });
});
```

While a class based approach does not:

```
describe('Chai throw() with new-style custom errors', ()=> {
  // New way
  class ExtendError extends Error {
    constructor(message = 'todo', value) {
      super(message);
      this.name = 'ExtendError';
      this.message = message;
    }
  }

  it('catches ExtendError', ()=> {
    var err = new ExtendError('This is a bad function.');
    var fn = function () { throw err; }
    expect(fn).to.throw(ExtendError);
    expect(fn).to.throw(Error);
    expect(fn).to.throw(/bad function/);
    expect(fn).to.not.throw('good function');
    expect(fn).to.throw(ExtendError, /bad function/);
    expect(fn).to.throw(err);
  });
});
```

I also implemented the related [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089801/extending-error-in-javascript-with-es6-syntax#answer-32749533). Though interesting, it still didn't work with mocha `throws()`. I'm basically happy to go with the ES5 style Errors, but I'm just unsure what the actual problem is. When I transpile the code for `ExtendError` I can't immediately see anything that would trip up the expect clause:

```
'use strict';

function _classCallCheck(instance, Constructor) { if (!(instance instanceof Constructor)) { throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function"); } }

function _possibleConstructorReturn(self, call) { if (!self) { throw new ReferenceError("this hasn't been initialised - super() hasn't been called"); } return call && (typeof call === "object" || typeof call === "function") ? call : self; }

function _inherits(subClass, superClass) {
    if (typeof superClass !== "function" && superClass !== null) {
        throw new TypeError("Super expression must either be null or a function, not " + typeof superClass);
    }
    subClass.prototype = Object.create(superClass && superClass.prototype, {
        constructor: {
            value: subClass,
            enumerable: false,
            writable: true,
            configurable: true
        }
    });
    if (superClass) Object.setPrototypeOf ? Object.setPrototypeOf(subClass, superClass) : subClass.__proto__ = superClass;
}

var ExtendError = function (_Error) {
  _inherits(ExtendError, _Error);

  function ExtendError() {
    var message = arguments.length <= 0 || arguments[0] === undefined ? 'todo' : arguments[0];
    var value = arguments[1];

    _classCallCheck(this, ExtendError);

    var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Error.call(this, message));

    _this.name = 'ExtendError';
    _this.message = message;
    return _this;
  }

  return ExtendError;
}(Error);
```

What is Mocha/Chai's problem?

Comment: @loganfsmyth  Hm, is this marked as duplicate because https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-transform-builtin-extend _should_ of worked? I did try your package, but  it didn't fix things in this case (perhaps too many moving parts and I made a mistake)

Comment: Not sure, that should fix it. I marked it as a dupe primarily because you're asking the same core question of "why isn't `instanceof` working here".

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have another go and report back

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with Chai. If you do `err instanceof ExtendError` with your ES6 implementation you'll get `false`!

The ES5 and ES6 implementations of `ExtendError` you run are actually operating differently.

- On the ES5 side, you call `Error` but do nothing with the return value. This is correct.
- On the ES6 side, the `super(...)` call is converted to

  ```
  var _this = _possibleConstructorReturn(this, _Error.call(this, message));`
  ```

  and then `_this` takes the place of `this` in the original ES6 code. The return value of `Error` is used in the ES6 code and this is where everything goes to hell because the object you then return from the constructor is an `Error` object but not an `ExtendError` object.

I would just continue to use the ES5 syntax to derive from `Error`. I've tried a few approaches to keep the ES6 syntax but in the end they were hybrid or did awful awful things. The least objectionable method I came up with was:

```
class ExtendError {
    constructor(message = 'todo', value) {
        Error.call(this, message);
        this.name = 'ExtendError';
        this.message = message;
    }
}

ExtendError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
ExtendError.prototype.constructor = ExtendError;
```

It is not making great use of the ES6 `class` sugar...