# How to declare a function that throws an error in Typescript

Tags: typescript

In Java I would declare a function like this:

```
public boolean Test(boolean test) throws Exception {
  if (test == true)
    return false;
  throw new Exception();
}
```

And I can use this function without handling the exception.

If it is possible, how to do the same in Typescript? The compiler will tell me that I can't use the function without a try/catch.

Comment: No it is not posible

Comment: Not sure if you are looking for `Error` class, check my answer below

Comment: You could annotate it via decorators to indicate that the method may throw, but there's nothing that can enforce that. You would have to inspect the annotation to check every time you called that method.

Comment: Not 100% sure what your goal is here -- if you return a boolean type, you're done. There's nothing you need to do to "use this function without handling the exception", I don't believe. Just as a for instance, I wanted to have a function that wrapped throwing an error (that is, the function would throw _every time_, versus your "half the outcomes"), and eventually decided on marking it as if it returned a specific type that matched the caller's other outcome. `const x = success ? handleX(x) : handleError(err)` where `handleX` and `handleError` "return" the same type.

Answer (score 178, accepted):

There is no such feature in TypeScript. It's possible to specify error type only if a function returns an error, not throws it (this rarely happens and is prone to be antipattern).

The only relevant type is [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never). It is applicable only if a function definitely throws an error, it cannot be more specific than that. It's a type as any other, it won't cause type error as long as it doesn't cause type problems:

```
function Test(): never => {
  throw new Error();
}

Test(); // won't cause type error
let test: boolean = Test(); // will cause type error
```

When there is a possibility for a function to return a value, `never` is absorbed by return type.

It's possible to specify it in function signature, but for reference only:

```
function Test(test: boolean): boolean | never {
  if (test === true)
    return false;

  throw new Error();
}
```

It can give a hint to a developer that unhandled error is possible (in case when this is unclear from function body), but this doesn't affect type checks and cannot force `try..catch`; the type of this function is considered `(test: boolean) => boolean` by typing system.

Comment: “`never` is omitted by typing system in favour of return type” … This is technically incorrect. The reason you don’t have to specify `never` in a return type is that in a union, every other type *absorbs* it. So `boolean|never` is simplified to `boolean`, like how `anything || false` simplifies to `anything`: in a disjunction, anything *absorbs* `false`. In a way, `never` is the opposite of [`unknown`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#new-unknown-top-type), which *dominates* in a union, and is *absorbed* in an intersection.

Comment: Thanks for the notice. Indeed, adsorption is the correct term here.

Comment: @chharvey Just a quick note: `anything || false` does not simplify to `anything` (unless you meant for `anything` to represent all truthy values, but that was unclear). If the left side of `||` is falsy, JavaScript takes the right side regardless of its value. Try `null || false` in your console and you'll see you get `false`.

Comment: @willurd yes it’s a minor technicality but you are right. i should have said `anything_truthy || false` simplifies to `anything_truthy`. thanks for the correction. the difference is that `anything_truthy || false` is an expression that *short-circuits* at runtime, whereas `boolean | never` is a type that statically simplifies.

Comment: @chharvey Yeah I figured that's what you meant. I just think it's important to be precise no matter how pedantic, especially for newer people that may be learning e.g. the intricacies of JavaScript.

Comment: Good point willurd :+1: - pedantic, accurate however you want to name it :-)

Comment: NIce, thanks for the `never` solution, it muted the compiler error forcing us to add `undefined` to the return type if we have a wrapper error handling function with `void`, which returns undefined by TS def. Basically `void vs never`.

Comment: @LeOn-HanLi Sounds interesting! Could you elaborate? Do you perhaps have a TypeScript Playground of your code?

Comment: This works out nicely when you follow a Result type flow and eventually may want to pass that Error to a handler that you expect to throw, this properly handles the logical type branching/flow properly, as long as the handler explicitly only throws it sounds like. I ultimately ended up having my handler report the error but not throw as I thought the consumer should handle the throwing, so the call to the method handles it, and then the consumer just throws from the error returned from the handler call.

Comment: `not throws it (this rarely happens and is prone to be antipattern).`

IMO it's a lot cleaner to handle this way but it's not how we do things in javascript

Answer (score 36):

You can mark the function with [`@throws`](https://jsdoc.app/tags-throws.html) jsdoc at least. Even though it does not provide static analysis errors in typescript compiler, some good IDE or linter may still [report a warning](https://github.com/gajus/eslint-plugin-jsdoc#eslint-plugin-jsdoc-rules-require-throws) if you try to disregard the function that throws...

```js
/** 
 * @throws {Error}
 */
function someFunc() {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) throw Error();
}
someFunc();
```

[image]

Comment: By your knowledge, is there any way to enable such a warning on Visual Studio Code? That would be tremendously helpful.

Comment: I checked eslint-plugin-jsdoc, but my understanding is that the require-throws rule only enforces exceptions to be documented in JSDoc. Sadly it does not enforce try-catch statements inside the code that makes use of the function, which is what many of us are looking for. Any alternatives?

Answer (score 25):

It is not possible at this moment. You can check out this requested feature: 
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219

Answer (score 2):

You could treat JavaScript's `Error` as Java's `RuntimeException` (unchecked exception).
You can extend JavaScript's `Error` but [you have to use `Object.setPrototypeOf`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#support-for-newtarget) to restore the prototype chain because `Error` breaks it. The need for setPrototypeOf is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48342359/2692914) too.

```
export class AppError extends Error {
    code: string;

    constructor(message?: string, code?: string) {
        super(message);  // 'Error' breaks prototype chain here
        Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);  // restore prototype chain
        this.name = 'AppError';
        this.code = code;
    }
}
```

Comment: This prototype change is not required for ES2015 and above, where inheriting from Error works as expected. If your transpilation targets ES2015+, you don't need to worry about it!

Comment: Can you give examples of how this solves the original question? To mark a function as a throwing one in TypeScript

Comment: An **unchecked** exception in Java is one that doesn't need to be declared on the method signature (throws Exception) and doesn't need to be handled. As far as I know Typescript doesn't have the notion of checked / unchecked exceptions. In Java terms: every Typescript exception is unchecked.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated in other answers, in typescript, the return type of a fallible operation is `never`. There is no way to mark a function as throws however you can use a utility type to make it more discernible:

```
type Result<OK = any> = OK | never;
```

Or you can make it even more noticeable:

```
type Result<OK = any, Error = never> = OK | Error;
```

Again, these are for the eyes only, no way to enforce try/catch block.

If you want to force handling of errors, use a promise. Linters can cath unhandled promises. "typescript-eslint" has "No floating promises" rule.

https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-floating-promises.md

Also some runtimes emit errors when there is an unhandled promise.

Answer (score 2):

Coming from a functional background, I prefer to specify expected errors (aka checked exceptions) in the return type. Typescript unions and type guards make this simple:

```
class ValidationError {
  constructor(readonly message: string) {}

  static isInstance(err: unknown): err is ValidationError {
    if (err === undefined) return false
    if (typeof err !== 'object') return false
    if (err === null) return false
    return err instanceof ValidationError
  }
}

function toInt(num: string): number | ValidationError {
  const result = Number.parseInt(num)
  if (result === undefined) return new ValidationError(`Invalid integer ${num}`)
  return result
}

// caller
const result = toInt("a")
if (ValidationError.isInstance(result))
  console.log(result.message)
else
  console.log(`Success ${result}`)
```

This way, the function signature highlights the potential error to other developers. More importantly the IDE & transpiler will force developers to deal with them (in most cases). For example this will fail:

```
const result = toInt("a")
const doubled = result * 2

error TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type
```

Comment: I often code in Rust and am currently exposed to a project dealing with TypeScript. I was looking for a workaround attempting to replicate Rust's `Result<T,E>` return type. This helped. Thanks.

Comment: PS. btw, for those coming from the same background as mine, I found this  https://github.com/franeklubi/rustic

Answer (score 1):

You cannot using pure ts (v<3.9) I hope it will be available in the future.
A workaround is however possible, it consists of hiding the possible thrown types in the method's signature to then recover those types in the catch block.
I made a package with this workaround here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-throwable/v/latest

usage is more or less as follow:

```js
import { throwable, getTypedError } from 'ts-throwable';
class CustomError extends Error { /*...*/ }

function brokenMethod(): number & throwable<CustomError> {
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) { return 42 };
    throw new CustomError("Boom!");
}

try {
    const answer: number = brokenMethod()
}
catch(error){
    // `typedError` is now an alias of `error` and typed as `CustomError` 
    const typedError = getTypedError(error, brokenMethod);
}
```

Comment: Just fyi `throw` isn't an expression so its usage here inside a ternary is incorrect

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a interesting PR to follow regarding this topic https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40468

This PR introduces:

- A new type-level expression: throw type_expr. Currently throw type
  only throws when it is being instantiated.
- A new intrinsic type
  TypeToString to print a type

Answer (score 0):

Not TypeScript, but [Hegel](https://hegel.js.org/) might be of interest which is another type-checker for JavaScript, and has this feature. You'd write:

```
function Test(test: boolean): boolean | $Throws<Exception> {
  if (test)
    return false;
  throw new Exception();
}
```

See https://hegel.js.org/docs/magic-types#throwserrortype

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible and likely won't be for a long time if ever.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219#issuecomment-1515037604
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13219#issuecomment-1806338593
There was a link previous to the general github discussion, however the github discussion thread is lengthy and closed, so I wanted to save people the effort of reading the dicussion and just link the two most relevant comments.

I cannot comment on the relevant answer which linked to this thread otherwise I would.

For an even more TLDR:
-TS team doesn't want to take the first step in normalizing typed errors since its not present in the community yet, and there doesn't exist any sort of typed error processing (like Java) within JS.