# should function returns include "never" if they can throw an exception

Tags: typescript

If I have a function that under normal circumstances returns a value, but can throw an exception what should the prototype look like? Should it include `| never` (e.g., a union of its normal return type and [`never`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#never))?

For example, is there reason to do the following? If nothing else it seems like it might point out possible exceptions to future coders.

```
function fn( n: number ) : number | never {
    if ( n < 0 ) throw ("badness");
    return n;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to declare a function that throws an error in Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49434751/how-to-declare-a-function-that-throws-an-error-in-typescript)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it might be a bit too dependent on opinion to be answerable. (the possible duplicate question only talks about the how, not about the 'should')

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't hurt, but there's not much point to doing that.  The `never` acts as a [bottom type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type) with no possible values, and is aggressively [removed from unions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#the-never-type) by the compiler:

> Because `never` is a subtype of every type, it is always omitted from union types and it is ignored in function return type inference as long as there are other types being returned.

That means if you inspect your function with something like [IntelliSense](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio#TypeInference), it will show up as:

```
function fn(n: number): number
```

so future coders are unlikely to even notice the difference.  And in practice, there is no difference, because it's very hard to guarantee that an exception *cannot* be thrown inside some function.

---

A safer but more annoying approach is to encode possible failure in your return type without relying on exceptions, such as:

```
function fn( n: number ) : number | undefined {
    if ( n < 0 ) return undefined;
    return n;
}
```

or even more verbose but very explicit about intent:

```
type Success<T> = { success: true, value: T };
type Error<E> = { success: false, error: E };
function fn(n: number): Success<number> | Error<string> {
  if (n < 0) return { success: false, error: "badness" };
  return { success: true, value: n };
}
```

It really depends on your use case.

---

Probably I'd just leave your original as-is and use [JSDoc](http://usejsdoc.org/) comments to hint about possible exceptions.

```
/** Returns n if n is non-negative, throws an exception otherwise */
function fn(n: number): number | never {
  if (n < 0) throw ("badness");
  return n;
}
```

If you are using an editor with [IntelliSense](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/JavaScript-Language-Service-in-Visual-Studio#JsDoc), the hints will show up:

[image: IntelliSense view]

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Very helpful, thanks!  I can't vote you up because my rep is too low :(