# ReferenceError: must call super constructor before using |this| in Ti class constructor

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a Angular project, recently updated to Angular 6 from Angular 5.2.10. Before the upgrade everything works fine.

Now, every time I compile my code for production, although there is no errors whatsoever during compile time, I receive this error when running:

```
ReferenceError: must call super constructor before using |this| in Ti class constructor
```

The only typescript class that use super is

```
export class Exception extends Error {
    private _statusCode: number;

    constructor(statusCode: number, type: ExceptionType) {
        super(ExceptionType[type]);
        this._statusCode = statusCode;
    }

    get statusCode(): number {
        return this._statusCode;
    }
}
```

Simple and plain. ExceptionType is an Enum.

The error is pretty self explanatory, but it seems I did the right thing, because Error class constructor has a single, optional parameter

```
Error(errorMsg?:string)
```

and this is called after the 'super' thing.

I'm numb.

**Edit**: tried the suggestion from comments, not working for me

**Edit 2**: as @estus pointed out, the error is not in this code but in

```
class Ei {
            constructor(l, n=Ei.now) {
                this.SchedulerAction = l,
                this.now = n
            }
            schedule(l, n=0, e) {
                return new this.SchedulerAction(this,l).schedule(e, n)
            }
        }
        Ei.now = Date.now ? Date.now : ()=>+new Date;
        class Ti extends Ei {
            constructor(l, n=Ei.now) {
                this.actions = [],
                this.active = !1,
                this.scheduled = void 0
            }
    ...
}
```

The affected row is

```
this.actions = []
```

Which has nothing to do with my code. I'll open a issue on github.

**Edit 3**: please check https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7799#issuecomment-386582136

Comment: `ExceptionType` is a type you are using as value in super.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript - Extending Error class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102060/typescript-extending-error-class)

Comment: It's still unclear why this error may be triggered. It's not evident that `Ti` class refers to `Exception`. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Comment: @fatemefazli, ExceptionType is an Enum, and using ExceptionType[type] return the associated string.

Comment: @estus, I don't know how give you and others here a working example without giving you a full access to repo. Exception class is shared between angular and other server side projects in the same solution. And there is no TI class in source code, I believe that name come from uglyfing.

Comment: The fact that the issue is only on production, could be caused to uglyfing?

Comment: You can click on the place in where the error happens in call stack to check where the error happens. You can likely recognize classes even if they are uglified. This may be caused either by minification or by AOT, although I don't see how any of them can affect the code that was posted, so it's likely not the case. Try to disable minification in production build and see what happens. Even if it's 6.0.0 bug, you'll need to provide a way to replicate it to post it in Angular issues.

Comment: @estus, thanks, you pointed to the right direction.