# Property 'setPrototypeOf' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'

Tags: typescript, polyfills, typescript3.0

I want to implement polyfill Object.setPrototypeOf as is descrbed in:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

It is my polyfill.ts:

```
// Only works in Chrome and FireFox, does not work in IE:
Object.setPrototypeOf = Object.setPrototypeOf || function(obj, proto) {
    obj.__proto__ = proto;
    return obj; 
}
```

polyfills.d.ts:

```
declare interface ObjectConstructor{

        setPrototypeOf(obj: any, proto: any);

}
```

I was trying with many possibilities of polyfill.d.ts:

```
declare global {

    export interface ObjectConstructor {
        setPrototypeOf(obj: any, proto: any);
    }
}
```

and still I have following error:

> [ts] Property 'setPrototypeOf' does not exist on type
>   'ObjectConstructor'. Did you mean 'getPrototypeOf'? lib.es5.d.ts(164,
>   5): 'getPrototypeOf' is declared here.

I migrate quite large application to TypeScript 3.0.3 that is why I need to implement the polyfill.

**Found solution:**

It is good enough to delete polyfill and:

```
export class KnownError extends Error {
    public isKnownError: boolean = true;

    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
        //good enough solution, transpiled to ES5
        (<any>Object).setPrototypeOf(this, KnownError.prototype)
    }
}
```

**More:** [Typescript - Extending Error class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102060/typescript-extending-error-class)

Comment: The first thing you tried for `polyfills.d.ts` should have worked.  Is `polyfills.d.ts` included by your `tsconfig.json` file?  If you jump to definition on `ObjectConstructor`, do you get a menu indicating that your declaration is being merged with the one in the standard library?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I think Your question is crucial. No. I do not see Object.setPrototypeOf. In polyfills.ts I see following error "[ts] Property 'setPrototypeOf' does not exist on type 'ObjectConstructor'. Did you mean 'getPrototypeOf'?
lib.es5.d.ts(164, 5): 'getPrototypeOf' is declared here.". It seems like polyfill.ts does not work. To solve my issue I read https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html

Comment: If you write `declare var foo: any;` in `polyfills.d.ts` and then reference `foo` from `polyfill.ts`, does the reference resolve to the declaration?  Maybe `polyfills.d.ts` is not included in your project.

Comment: Thank you for posting the found solution. Only it would be better to put it in own answer because people often read only the beginning of the question an go to the answers.

Comment: I think the solution is to bitch to the TS people to be honest. The polyfills solution is a crutch - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

Comment: I have one question not directly related to the problem...why Object.setPrototypeOf (in polyfill.ts) is called without arguments?...the syntax is this Object.setPrototypeOf(obj, prototype)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way how I coped with that (not ideal) solution:

```js
export class KnownError extends Error {
    public isKnownError: boolean = true;

    constructor(message: string) {
        super(message);
        this.message = message;
        //good enough solution, transpiled to ES5
        (<any>Object).setPrototypeOf(this, KnownError.prototype)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add to the tsconfig.json this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      ...
      "es7"
    ]
  }
}
```