# How Error class could be extended in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is there a way to extend `Error` in TypeScript >= 3.3 so it would correctly work with `instanceof`?

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(
                    message: string,
    public readonly details: string
  ) { super(message) }
}

try {
  throw new MyError('some message', 'some details')
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)            // Ok
  console.log(e.details)            // Ok
  console.log(e instanceof MyError) // Wrong, prints false
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31626231/custom-error-class-in-typescript

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @moronator, you have to add magic line

```
class MyError extends Error {
  constructor(
                    message: string,
    public readonly details: string
  ) { 
    super(message) 

    // This line
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, MyError.prototype)
  }
}

try {
  throw new MyError('some message', 'some details')
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e.message)            // Ok
  console.log(e.details)            // Ok
  console.log(e instanceof MyError) // Works
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52402166/property-setprototypeof-does-not-exist-on-type-objectconstructor

Comment: See first comment answered by @moronator, there's the link to the answer