# Why is an object constructed from a subclass of Error not considered an instanceof the subclass?

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an abstract class such as this.

```
abstract class AppException extends Error {
  // constructor, functions, whatever   
}
```

Let's also say I have a class like

```
class NotFoundException extends AppException {
}
```

Now I have an object error of type `Error` in a random function. I passed an instance of `NotFoundException` to the function.

In the error, if I try to do

```
if (error instanceof AppException) {
return something;
} 
return otherThing;
```

The expression in the if statement returns false and it returns `otherThing` when I'm sure I've passed `NotFoundException` to the function which accepts object of type `Error`.

Is there anything wrong I'm approaching with types in typescript?

NOTE: I'm using this AppException to propagate errors to a global error handler in ExpressJS.

EDIT:
This is what I'm trying to do

```
abstract class AppException extends Error {}
class NotFoundException extends AppException {}

async function getRegisterController(
    req: Request,
    res: Response,
    next: NextFunction,
): Promise<Response | undefined> {
    // business logic
    next(new NotFoundException('User not found');
    return;
 }

 this.server.use(
    (err: Error, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
        if (err instanceof AppException) {
           // doens't work here
           logger.error(`AppException status code ${err.getStatusCode()}`);
        }
    },
);
```

These are two middleware functions I'm using in expressjs. In the `getRegisterController`, I'm calling next() and passing an instance of NotFoundException to the next(). This inturn calls the other middleware and passes the object I sent as error object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Typescript - Extending Error class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41102060/typescript-extending-error-class)

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided looks correct with the only exception being you need `instanceof` (all lowercase):

```js
abstract class AppException extends Error {}

class NotFoundException extends AppException {}

const error = new NotFoundException();

const test = () => {
  if (error instanceof AppException) {
    return "something";
  }
  return "otherThing";
};

console.log(test()) // Print "something" in the console
```

[TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggB2wUQA9YBTbCASwHsA7BYgiY6gEwzyikqgQG8BfAFACUaDADlKEAGKUAri0IkyVWvUYsMOfEVIUavQcJqQ6HLggC8CasQDuCCdLkKdymgAoAlAG4hsY4iMJlZelgB8vAIICOQAZgjuxGbc5NSQwNQklPFairoqnpHR0VDEELJQtABEYJQAtmUAFqkA5lW+0YIlZRXVko1JACrN1G2+fL5GaZTIxAB0yJQt7kEQXp5AA)

Comment: I do have `instanceof` in my code. I made the typo while typing here. It doesn't work with this too.

Comment: @SriramR this answers shows that the bug is in your code. The code that you haven't posted. You think you're passing an instance of AppException, but you're not. If you did, it would return "something", as this answer proves.

Comment: One problem with your answer is that my function accepts an error parameter which is of type Error. In your answer,  the error object is of type NotFoundException which is what I'm passing, but the function receives the error as an `Error` object.

Comment: @SriramR http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgggB2wUQA9YBTbCASwHsA7BYgiY6gEwzyikqgQG8BfAFACUaDADlKEAGKUAri0IkyVWvUYsMOfEVIUavQcJqQ6HLggC8CasQDuCCdLkKdymgAoAlAG4hsY4iMJlbuxABcCOycUJ6WAHy8AggI5ABmCKEp1JDA1CSU6VqKuiqxPEnJCFDEELJQtABEYJQAtjUAFuTUAOYNvsmCydW19QgNku3EUAAqnT19Any+RtmUyMQAdMiU3e5BEKFmMZ5AA. Again, the problem is in the code you didn't post We can't help you find your mistake if you don't post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Oh yes, I understand. Let me post the real example.

Answer (score 0):

You tsconfig target is proabably `ES5`. You need to set the prototype manually since `typescrtipt>=2.2` or use a newer target.

```
abstract class AppException extends Error {
  constructor() {
    super();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, AppException.prototype);
  }
}

class NotFoundException extends AppException {
  constructor() {
    super();
    Object.setPrototypeOf(this, NotFoundException.prototype);
  }
}

const notFoundException = new NotFoundException();

console.log(notFoundException instanceof AppException);
```

Check the [typescript team explanation](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-wiki/blob/master/Breaking-Changes.md#extending-built-ins-like-error-array-and-map-may-no-longer-work) for more info