# Throwing custom error class results in instanceof Error instead of custom error class

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

I have made some specific error classes like `NotFoundError`, `ConflictError` and `UnauthorizedError`. There all extends a `BaseError` which is an extension of Nodejs' Error class.

When throwing one of my custom made errors, I should expect that the instance of that error is the class name of the chosen error. For example for `throw new UnauthorizedError('Missing api-key')` I expect the error to have an instance of `UnauthorizedError`. This is not the case as the incoming error in my errorHandler middleware is of instance Error.

I need this instance to handle specific responses back to the client based on the instance as shown here below.

**error-handler.middleware.ts**

```
export const errorHandler = (error: unknown, req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log('Instance of', error?.constructor.name);

    if (error instanceof ValidationError) {
        return res.status(error.status).json({ errors: error.errors });
    }

    if (error instanceof UnauthorizedError) {
        return res.status(error.status).send({ error: error.message });
    }

    if (error instanceof BaseError) {
        return res.status(error.status).send({ error: error.message });
    }

    if (error instanceof Error) {
        return res.status(HttpCode.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).json({
            message: 'Internal Server Error',
        });
    }

    next();
};
```

What I'm a missing out or doing wrong? Below some more code about the pieces I talked about.

**base.error.ts**

```
export class BaseError extends Error {
    status: number;
    message: string;

    constructor(status: number, message: string) {
        super(message);

        this.status = status;
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**unauthorized.error.ts**

```
import { BaseError } from './base.error';

export class UnauthorizedError extends BaseError {
    message: string;

    constructor(message: string = 'Unauthorized to perform this action') {
        super(HttpCode.UNAUTHORIZED, message);
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**api-key-handler.middleware.ts**

```
export const validateApiKey = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    const code = req.headers['x-api-key'] as string;

    if (!code) {
        throw new UnauthorizedError('Missing api-key');
    }

    next();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `Object.setPrototypeOf(this, new.target.prototype);` in the constructor of the **base.error.ts** fixed it.

Found the answer in this post [Typescript - Extending Error class](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58417721/1391416) (answer from @Grabofus)