# Is it possible to modify error messages based on the status of the error?

Tags: reactjs, error-handling, react-admin

Is there a possibility how to overwrite those temporary error messages that are displayed when an error occured? For example, when there is an error with `500` status, the `front-end` displays an error: `Internal Server Error`. I would like to check if the error has a status of 500 and then to overwrite the message to something more specific.
So far I have tried to put this code into my `AuthProvider.js` but it does not seem to work for me.

```
if (type === AUTH_ERROR) {
  const status = params.status;
  if (status === 500) {
    throw new Error('ErrorMessage');
  }
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

I checked the value of `status` and it is 500. but the message stays the same.

Any ideas how to solve this?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to observe precise message in console log, you can do something as below:

```
{
    console.error('Auth failed');
}
```

Since you clarified that I assumed your purpose wrongly, below is the code to fulfill your request of throwing customized error:

```
function CommonException(message, code)
{
    this.message = message;
    this.code = code;
}

try
{
    var exception = new CommonException('ErrorMessage', 500);

    throw exception;

    alert('Whatever');
}
catch (e) {
    alert(e.message);
    alert(e.code)
}
```

Comment: No. I would like to check if the error has a status of 500 and then to overwrite the message to something more specific.

That is what I want to achieve, not to `console.log` variables or strings.

Comment: Besides, if you mean you only want to extend Error, please check with this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31089801/extending-error-in-javascript-with-es6-syntax-babel