# Custom Javascript Error.toString()

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

My custom Error class:

```
function MyError(message) {
  this.message = message || "";
}

MyError.prototype          = new Error();
MyError.prototype.name     = "MyError";
MyError.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "[" + this.name + "] " + this.message;
};
```

If I run `throw new MyError("test")` then FF/IE console shows a default message instead of the expected `[MyError] test`.

How do I get the JS engine to use my `toString()` method?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `MyError.prototype = Error.prototype`?

Comment: A solution would be to not inherit from Error.

Comment: @fardjad nope [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/871646/1711500)

Comment: @dystroy I guess that's true, but there are benefits to doing so (other standard and non-standard properties which are useful)

Comment: @BobbyB I know, that's why I only made a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @dystroy +1 It was a good comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be mistaken, but I think the console output in this case is controlled by the JS engine, and so you cannot format it as I've done above.

Comment: Yes, that's probably true. But why would you want to change that anyway?

Comment: Some other tool which is parsing the output. I'll need to change it.

Comment: Can you show us that tool? I'm positive that there is a better solution.

Comment: You are right, not worth the effort. Besides, I am sure it displays differently in different browsers. I thought it would behave the same as overriding toString() on any other object, but seems the Error class is "special".

Comment: Even if it's not very satisfying, this is probably the right answer. I  suggest you accept it.

Comment: @dystroy Must wait two days

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would inherit `Error` (tested and working on **FF v20**):

```
function MyError(message) {
    this.message = message || "";
}

MyError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype); // see the note
MyError.prototype.name = "MyError";
MyError.prototype.toString = function () { 
    return "[" + this.name + "] " + this.message;
}

console.log(new MyError("hello").toString()); // "[MyError] hello"
```

Note that old browsers may not support `Object.create` (**ES5** syntax), you can use [this](https://github.com/fardjad/realistic-typewriter.js/blob/master/src/object.create-shim.js) shim to make it work.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't exhibit the expected behavior when you do this: `throw new MyError("hello");` it still shows a default message. The way listed above is functionally equivalent to this, but a bit safer. I have a feeling this has to do with the browser's JS engine, and so I cannot change it.

Comment: Actually `throw new MyError('hello')` works fine for me in **FF**.

Comment: @BobbyB You're probably right, since `Error` class is bound to native code, the behavior will depend on the JavaScript engine implementation. Anyways [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nWlv5.png)'s a screenshot of the code running on my browser.