# Correct way to create custom errors in javascript

Tags: javascript

What is the correct way to define a custom error in JavaScript?

Searching through SO I've found about 6 different ways to define a custom error, but I'm unsure as to the (dis)advantages to each of them.

From my (limited) understanding of prototype inheritance in JavaScript, this code should be sufficient:

```
function CustomError(message) {
   this.name = "CustomError";
   this.message = message;
}
CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
```

Comment: somewhat related here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783818/how-do-i-create-a-custom-error-in-javascript

Comment: that was the main SO question that confused me. the highest ranked answer lists two different ways for the custom error to inherit from the `Error` object, neither of which is using the `Object.create()` method. the other answers seem to be variations of this theme.

Comment: `Object.create` is merely a new way of doing `CustomError.prototype = new Error()` -- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create

Comment: @n0w Related: [Benefits of using `Object.create` for inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392857/benefits-of-using-object-create-for-inheritance)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually I just use `throw new Error(...)`, but for custom errors I find the following code works pretty well and still gives you stack traces on V8, i.e. in Chrome and node.js (which you don't get just by calling `Error.apply()` as suggested in the other answer):

```
function CustomError(message) {
    // Creates the this.stack getter
    if (Error.captureStackTrace) Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
    this.message = message;
}
CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
CustomError.prototype.constructor = CustomError;
CustomError.prototype.name = 'CustomError';
```

For more info, see these links:

[What's a good way to extend Error in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1382107/whats-a-good-way-to-extend-error-in-javascript)

https://plus.google.com/+MalteUbl/posts/HPA9uYimrQg

Comment: thanks. this seems to work correctly while also defining `this.stack` where available. the only change i'll make in my own code is to also define `this.name` in the constructor.

Comment: Good suggestion; I've added that in (did it on the prototype since the name is the same for all instances, but it doesn't really matter).

Comment: Note: for fuller compatibility with IE, a few other things are needed; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8460753/560114.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest of course, and in my opinion, the best to use unless you need more complex error reporting/handling is this:

```
throw Error("ERROR: This is an error, do not be alarmed.")
```

Answer (score 1):

This script depicts all the possible mechanisms for creating and using custom errors in JavaScript.

Also to get a complete understanding, it's essential to have an understanding of prototypal inheritance and delegation in JavaScript.
I wrote this article which explains it clearly. https://medium.com/@amarpreet.singh/javascript-and-inheritance-90672f53d53c

I hope this helps.

```
function add(x, y) {
      if (x && y) {
        return x + y;
      } else {
        /**
         * 
         * the error thrown will be instanceof Error class and InvalidArgsError also
         */
        throw new InvalidArgsError();
        // throw new Invalid_Args_Error(); 
      }
    }

    // Declare custom error using using Class
    class Invalid_Args_Error extends Error {
      constructor() {
        super("Invalid arguments");
        Error.captureStackTrace(this);
      }
    }

    // Declare custom error using Function
    function InvalidArgsError(message) {
      this.message = `Invalid arguments`;
      Error.captureStackTrace(this);
    }
    // does the same magic as extends keyword
    Object.setPrototypeOf(InvalidArgsError.prototype, Error.prototype);

    try{
      add(2)
    }catch(e){
      // true
      if(e instanceof Error){
        console.log(e)
      }
      // true
      if(e instanceof InvalidArgsError){
        console.log(e)
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function CustomError() {
   var returned = Error.apply(this, arguments);
   this.name = "CustomError";
   this.message = returned.message;
}
CustomError.prototype = Object.create(Error.prototype);
//CustomError.prototype = new Error();

var nie = new CustomError("some message");

console.log(nie);
console.log(nie.name);
console.log(nie.message);
```