# How can I always throw error with express-validator?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, error-handling

Does express-validator provide error method which always throw error?
(Latest version: v3.1.2)

I'm using following custom method, but if there is smarter way, I would like to know.

```
app.use(expressValidator({
  customValidators: {
    fail: function() {
      return false;
    }
  }
}));
```

Thank you.

Comment: What is the use case? Why you want to create this custom method in express-validator? Can you use nodejs custom errors instead? Please see this example. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/783818/how-do-i-create-a-custom-error-in-javascript