# Intentionally create new error in Javascript to check code behavior

Tags: javascript, error-handling

In order to test how the front-end responds to various HTTP status error codes, I want to intentionally return an Error from one of my front-end service methods to simulate an Error from one of the API endpoints. The question is... how to do it in a more detailed manner.

I tried using the `new Error()` constructor, but I can see that I just have the option to add a message as argument to the constructor. I would also want to mock a status code, like for example `500`.

The question that was pointed as a potential solution, [How do I create a custom Error in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783818/how-do-i-create-a-custom-error-in-javascript), does not solve my problem. In the question and answers it is mentioned that the person wants to simply throw a new error with a name and a message, while I would also want to be able to throw different Error codes.

Comment: I think you are missing context in your question. It looks like you want to simulate e.g. a http:500 error code, but attempt to use `throw new Error();`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you talking about errors, just in the context of frontend or backend?

Comment: If just doing a quick manual test, you can hard set a status code via the library you're using to create your API. As a better approach, consider writing tests while mocking API responses. Check out mountebank (http://www.mbtest.org).

Answer (score 0):

You can throw an error with

```js
throw "SimpulatedException";
```

Depending on the framework you are using (I assume [expressjs](https://expressjs.com/) as it is the most popular) you can also just comment out the actual route an just return an error.

```js
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.status(500) //HTTP Statuscode
    res.json({
        status: 500, //Having the statuscode down in the body is needed for some frameworks.
        msg: "An error, just for testing" //An errormessage to display for the user
    }) //Body
})
```

Comment: I am using Vue.js and axios, and don't seem to find a way to mock and error through axios.