# catching an error somehow affecting object evaluation

Tags: javascript, error-handling, try-catch

I have a code structure like this:

```
class CustomError {
  constructor(status, error = null, message = null) {
    this.status = status;
    this.error = error;
    this.message = message;
  }
}

const foo = async function() {
  throw new CustomError('foo error');
}

const bar = async function() {
  try {
    foo();
  } catch (error) {
    if (error instanceof CustomError) {
      throw error;
    }
    throw new CustomError('bar error');
  }
}

bar();
```

This throws bar error.

I placed this before the `if` statement: 
`console.log(error instanceof CustomError, error)`
which logs:

```
false
CustomError {status: "foo", message: null, error: null}
```

this seems contradictory. If it logs `error` as `CustomError` shouldn't `error instanceof CustomError` return `true`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I create a custom Error in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/783818/how-do-i-create-a-custom-error-in-javascript)